# How to center the Google reCaptcha V2 checkbox in html

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

**Hi! I wanna center the Google reCaptcha V2 checkbox middle in my contact form... But I don't know how to do it. I also tried** `<div style=" margin:0 auto;"></div>` Can someone please help me with this? [This is the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTI78.png)
and
[This is how it is now. I wanna bring it to the red mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Ai6.png)

This is my website:- https://lasterleague.tk

My contact form:- https://lasterleague.tk/contact.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto;`  will work fine if width of element is defined and not auto, and also you have to use this `margin: 0 auto` property in right place. In your code you have to make some changes where you have written (I copied this from your contact form):

```
<div style=" width:304px; height : 78px">...</div>
```

change it to :

```
 <div style="margin:0 auto; width:304px; height : 78px">...</div>
```